# multiple pdf download for authenticated user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I am trying to download multiple pdf that belongs to the **authenticated user**
please how can I achieve this using **Laravel**

Comment: you should share your attempt so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply place a `@if Auth::User()` then you can show the URL to the user to download e.g. `<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">`. If you want to download multiple files you can show multiple links in the if condition.

Comment: please what does the rel="noopener" does

Comment: The noopener is needed to enhance the security of your website and prevent other websites from gaining access to your page (through the browser session). The noreferrer is used to protect referral information from being passed to the target website and this also hides referral traffic in Google analytics.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to keep track of who is downloading the documents in a shared table in laravel

Comment: You can develop your own algo for keeping track of the people who're downloading the documents.